# Tricky ClojureScript syntax

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Can anyone please help me understanding, what is going on in this piece of code:

```
(defn- make-edit-mode-container [widget]
  (let [input-container (template/node [:input.editable-edit-mode {:type "text"}])
        ghandler (goog.events.KeyHandler. input-container)]
      (set! (. input-container -gEditableHandler) ghandler)
  ;; ...
  ;; ...
  input-container))
```

As I understand, here a private function is declared, it accepts a `widget` parameter. The local-scope variable `input-container` is a node (actually it is a `dommy.template` node) which is a HTML `<input type="text" class="editable-edit-mode">` element.

What I can't undestand is `(goog.events.KeyHandler. input-container)` (e.g. what is dot doing at the end of `goog.events.Keyhandler`).

Consequently, AFAIU `(. input-container -gEditableHandler)` is a member access, but then where `-gEditableHandler` comes from and what does the dash mean?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(goog.events.KeyHandler. input-container)` is calling the KeyHandler as constructor hence it is equals to this js code : `new goog.events.KeyHandler(input-container);`

`(. input-container -gEditableHandler)` is accessing the property `gEditableHandler` of `input-container`, the - before `gEditableHandler` indicate to the compiler that it is a property access and not a method call (as method call also have same syntax i.e `(. obj method)`)